# What main class should i give in my manifest.mf of a jar file which has an applet without main class?

Tags: video, audio, file, applet, manifest.mf

i am having a applet(not having a main class) and i am having song file (beep.au) and picture file ( a.gif){these 2 files i have used in my applet} and i have created a jar file a.jar which contains the applet class , song file and picture file ... but when i run the jar file i get an error    :- Main-Class manifest-attribute not found .... what should i have to do to do to run the jar file???? (what main class should i give to the manifest.mf as my applet is not having a main method so no main class)

Answer (score 1):

Do you get this error when you try to run the applet in a web browser, or are you trying to run the applet from the command line?

If you are making an applet, you need to create an html page.  In that page you create an applet tag with the code attribute set to the "main" Applet class.

Comment: well with the web browser its fine... but i want to run it from command line  (as a normal applet can be run using appletviewer) something like that....

Comment: and with the browser also.. the browser is not using .jar file instead using .class file so no use of creating .jar in that case also